# Polars predicate push-down against Azure Blob Storage Parquet file?

Tags: python-polars

I am working with some large parquet files in Azure blob storage (1m rows+, ~100 columns), and I'm using `polars` to analyze this data.

I have no issue reading the data from azure via

```py
df = pl.read_parquet('az://{bucket-name}/{filename}.parquet', storage_options={...})
```

But this is sub-optimal in that it reads the entire file at once, which is slow and not always necessary.

I tried replacing the above with `pl.scan_parquet()` as follows:

```py
df = (
    pl.scan_parquet('az://{bucket-name}/{filename}.parquet', storage_options={...})
    .filter(pl.col('date') == pl.date(2023,4,1) )
    .collect()
    )
```

But this is just as slow as reading the entire file (despite only returning a very small fraction of the original file).

To me this seems like the file is being downloaded anyways ahead of filtering, which in a way makes sense because the compute for polar's couldn't reasonably be pushed to Azure Blob Storage.

However, is there anything I'm missing?

Two points to clarify:

1. I'm aware I could break the parquet file into multiple files (eg. indexed by date). I will do this if I have to but it'd require some code rework which I'd love to avoid.
2. In this context I need all the columns

Comment: Do your parquet files have statistics and row_groups that fit the filtering?

Comment: I'm not sure - how do I check

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_metadata.html